# npm install tries to install grpc 1.20.0 when version 1.24.2 is in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

When I run an npm install on my React-Native project I get the following error that says its trying to install gRPC version 1.20.0, but in my package.json and package.json.lock it has gRPC version 1.24.1.

I have tried changing the versions of the npm and grpc and still get the same error.

[image]

Comment: As I can see, `gRPC version 1.20.0` is one of the dependencies of package `firebase`, so when npm install firebase first, it will install `gRPC version 1.20.0`. Did you try to update `firebase` package?

Comment: Yes this worked thank you. I updated firebase from 5.5.9 to 6.1.0 and worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I'e posted my answer. But be noticed that you may need to change some codes after upgrading package , you can check it here: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at the first line, `gRPC version 1.20.0` is installing as an dependency of package `firebase`.

So when npm install firebase first, it will install `gRPC version 1.20.0`, not the version in your package.json.

If you upgrage your firebase version,the following command should works:

```
npm update firebase
```

Hope this helps!